# Eclipse Mars (4.5) Stuck Building Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently updated to Eclipse Mars (4.5) from Eclipse Luna (4.4). After importing a Gradle project, Eclipse Mars would get stuck when attempting to build the workspace.

I have one Gradle project that contains three sub-projects. Importing this project into Eclipse will create four projects (i.e., the root project and the three sub-projects). This is a non-trivial project. If anyone is interested, here is the [link](https://github.com/ChrisZhong/organization-model) to the project on GitHub.

I have isolated the problem to this JUnit test file [XmlParserTest.java](https://github.com/ChrisZhong/organization-model/blob/master/model/src/test/java/model/organization/parsers/XmlParserTest.java#L167).

For some reason, the following code would cause Eclipse Mars to get stuck when building the workspace.

```
assertThat(organization.getAchieves(r1).stream().map(SpecificationGoal::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)), hasItem(g1));
```

If I comment out all similar code in the `XmlParserTest.java`, Eclipse Mars would finish building the workspace. Eclipse Luna has no such problem.

I am stumped as to the cause of this problem. Any help I can get on resolving this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem with the same `assert` but a simplified version of your code (https://gist.github.com/ferstl/085e9a4ea34a2ffed620) and created a flight recording. It shows that the compiler got stuck while capturing the type parameters in your `assert`. This looks like a bug. I suggest you report it on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be filing a bug report on this. Do you mind if I use your simplified version as an example in the bug report?

Comment: Feel free to use it.

Comment: @Chris, did you open a bug report in the end? If yes, could you paste the link in this issue please?

Comment: Someone opened a similar bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471904